# How create proxy class from wsdl?

Tags: c#, wsdl

```
C: \ Program Files \ Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0 \ VC> svcutil wsdl.wsdl / out: Proxy.
Microsoft (R) Service Model Metadata Tool
[Microsoft (R) Windows (R) Communication Foundation, Version 3.0.4506.2152]
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Error: Can not import wsdl: portType
Details: Generated an exception at run time extension of import WSDL:
System.ServiceModel.Description.DataContractSerializerMessageContractImporter
Error: element complexType "http://api-new.begun.ru/index.php:Region" is already a Listing
flax.
XPath to Error Source: / / wsdl: definitions [@ targetNamespace = 'http://api-new.be
gun.ru / index.php '] / wsdl: portType [@ name =' AdvertiserServicePortType ']


Error: Can not import wsdl: binding
Details: Failed to import wsdl: portType, on which the wsdl: binding.
XPath to wsdl: portType: / / wsdl: definitions [@ targetNamespace = 'http://api-new.begun
.ru / index.php '] / wsdl: portType [@ name =' AdvertiserServicePortType ']
XPath to Error Source: / / wsdl: definitions [@ targetNamespace = 'http://api-new.be
gun.ru / index.php '] / wsdl: binding [@ name =' AdvertiserServiceBinding ']


Error: Can not import wsdl: port
Details: Failed to import wsdl: binding, which depends on the wsdl: port.
XPath to wsdl: binding: / / wsdl: definitions [@ targetNamespace = 'http://api-new.begun.
ru / index.php '] / wsdl: binding [@ name =' AdvertiserServiceBinding ']
XPath to Error Source: / / wsdl: definitions [@ targetNamespace = 'http://api-new.be
gun.ru / index.php '] / wsdl: service [@ name =' AdvertiserService '] / wsdl: port [@ name =' Adve
rtiserServicePort ']


Generating files ...
Warning: No code was generated.
If you were trying to generate a client, this could be because the metadata docu
ments did not contain any valid contracts or services
or because all contracts / services were discovered to exist in / reference assembl
ies. Verify that you passed all the metadata documents to the tool.

Warning: If you would like to generate data contracts from schemas make sure to
use the / dataContractOnly option.
```

how to fix it? I need proxy class in C#

**update:**

http://www.2shared.com/file/JAoRmgXI/wsdl.html

Comment: I don't understand your question... esp. because of the error messages being russian(?)... other relevant information needed to help: what .NET version are you using ? seeing the WSDL itsefl might help a lot too!

Comment: the update does not really help... can you post the .NET version you use AND the error messages in english please ?

Comment: Sorry I did not notice that the Russian

Comment: was the WSDL made by hand, or extracted using a tool?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess the wsdl references some other files (.xsd ?) that aren't in same directory.

**Update:** First error about *Region* is there because *Region* is defined twice (lines 253 and 274).
**Update2:** *RegionArray* is also declared twice. Client proxy generation works by removing the two twice declarations and using **wsdl.exe**: `wsdl.exe wsdl.wsdl /out:Proxy.cs`.

Comment: Do you want to generate a **client-side** proxy?